# C++ Randomized string output issue's

Tags: c++, visual-studio

can someone help me understand why my code is not outputting the way I expect?

main.cpp

```
int main() {

Test test;

test.OutPut();

return 0;
```

}

Test.h

```
class Test
{
private:
    string password;

    string password1;
    string password2;
    string password3;
    
public:
    char GetArrayChar();
    string RandomizedString();
    void setString();
    void OutPut();
    
public:
    //Array varibles 
    const static int Max_value = 62;
    int Size = sizeof(Array_char) - 1;

public:
    char Array_char[Max_value] = {
    '0', '1', '2', '3', '4','5', '6', '7', '8', '9',
    'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F','G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K','L',
    'M', 'N', 'O', 'P','Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U','V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z',
    'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f','g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k','l',
    'm', 'n', 'o', 'p','q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u','v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z' };
};
```

Test.cpp

```
char Test::GetArrayChar() {
    return Array_char[rand() % Size];
}

string Test::RandomizedString() {

    string password = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        password += GetArrayChar();
    }
    return password;
}

void Test::setString() {

    srand(time(0));
    string password1 = password;
    string password2 = password;
    string password3 = password;
}

void Test::OutPut() {

    cout << "Password1 is >> " << password1 << flush;
    cout << "\nPassword2 is >> " << password2 << flush;
    cout << "\nPassword3 is >> " << password3 << flush;
}
```

It works when i put the code from Output() and setString() in the same function. Is there a way i can get it to work in a similar manner to how it is already? or is it just better syntax to have the code from Output() & setString() in the same function? thanks

Comment: In future, when making statements about things not working the way you expect, it's helpful to actually describe _what_ you expect.  In this case, I can clearly see that your `setString` function is overriding the `password1` _etc_ variables with local variables.  These hide the ones that exist inside your object.  The quick fix is to remove `string` from those three lines.  But of course, you need to get a value for `password` too.  Perhaps call `RandomizedString`?  And you're also never calling `setString` in any case.  It's a bit of a mess, really.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside `setString`, this line:

```
string password1 = password;
```

creates a *new* local variable, it does not modify the instance variable. Hence on return from that function, the local variable is discarded and instance variable remains unchanged.

You may want to try:

```
password1 = password;
```

This is also a problem in `randomizedString` but, since you *return* the local (and will presumably assign it to the instance password variable), that may not be a problem.

---

As an aside, you also don't seem to call `RandomizedString`, which I'm pretty certain is a prerequisite for setting the password to something other than the default. Ditto for not calling `setString`, which would be required to transfer that password to the other three password variables.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues with your code.

1. methods setString & RandomizedString works with local variables and don't change object data fields
2. If you want your code in main.cpp to work, you probably need to include all data initialization in default constructor Test::Test()

Answer (score 0):

Ok thanks to paxdiablo and everyone else for the help and yes in future i will explain what i expect i thought would happen. anyway i did what paxdiablo said and added the other function call to main

```
int main() {

Test test;

test.RandomizedString();
test.setString();
test.OutPut();


return 0;
```

}

and i also changed `setString()`

```
void Test::setString() {
    
    srand(time(0));
    password1 = RandomizedString();
    password2 = RandomizedString();
    password3 = RandomizedString();
}
```

and this outputs the three randomized string i was looking for so thanks again